# Regular Expression to find number after word with special characters and subtract constant value

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using `notepad++`, trying to find number after word with special characters and then subtract constant number from the value for all such occurrence.

Input:

```
<title>100
<title>99
<title>98
<title>97
```

Expected output after `regex`, using find and replace:

```
<title>78
<title>77
<title>76
<title>75
```

There is always a difference of 22 between input number and the output.

Tried using below expression, but it only finds all the word with special characters that has `<` and `>` before and after.

```
<(.+?)>
```

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Can you use language(s)? You have better languages than an editor like notepad. Let us know.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - I can use ````R````, but I thought of using ````regex```` and ````notepad++````, to see if it is achievable with expressions.

Comment: Sure you can add r tag to it. Also not my downvote btw, cheers.

Comment: No, doing mathematic operations with regex alone is not possible. Use a regex to match the number and an actual programming language to do the substraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a python script within the PythonScript plugin.

If it is not yet installed, follow this [guide](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above)

- Create a script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script)
- Copy this code and save the file (for example substract.py):

```py
import re

def substract(match):
    val = int(match.group(1)) - 22
    return str(val)
    
editor.rereplace(r'<title>\K(\d+)', substract)
```

- Open the file you want to modify
- Run the script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> substract)
- Done

Comment: Toto - Thank you , this was helpful and worked.

Answer (score 1):

If using another text editor -EmEditor , it's easy to do Arithmetic operation in search & replace function by J mode.

Find: **(?<=\<title>)\d+**

Replace :**\J \0-22**

**(?<=\<title>)\d+** use look -around pattern, which means find the numbers after .

**\J \0-22** use J mode by **\J** , **\0** is back reference for found numbers. The result of \0-22 is we wanted . Certainly , we can calculate by + - * / and others.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XkO9.jpg)